# Coloring individual patches in Mayavi

Tags: python, matplotlib, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

[I can do this with matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEdw5.png) I want to plot a torus and vary the coloring of the surface based on the small angle parameter. More generally, how do you color individual patches when you plot a surface with Mayavi?

I can do this easily in matplotlib using the 'facecolors' parameter when I plot, but because I need better 3D rendering I have to use Mayavi.

Moreover, here is how you can color individual points in Mayavi: 
[Plotting 3D points with different colors in Mayavi (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263312/plotting-3d-points-with-different-colors-in-mayavi-python) 
But I haven't found something similar to work for surfaces.

From the documentation, the coloring is specified by default by the elevation z but I am not sure how I can change this to be specified based on some array I can pass to the plotting function.

Is there a way, to change this dependency?

'''

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

mlab.options.offscreen = True

R = 2
r = 1

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 20)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 20)
torus = np.zeros((3,20,20))

for i in range(0,20):
    for j in range(0,20):
        torus[0][i][j] = (R + r * np.cos(phi[j])) * np.cos(theta[i])
        torus[1][i][j] = (R + r * np.cos(phi[j])) * np.sin(theta[i])
        torus[2][i][j] = r * np.sin(phi[j])


mlab.mesh(torus[0], torus[1], torus[2])
mlab.show()
```

'''

I want the result to look like the following:

[image: torus]

Comment: It would help if you could provide the `matplotlib` code